# python regex search for elimitation

Tags: regex, python-2.7

i have the following case

```
import re

target_regex = '^(?!P\-[5678]).*'
pattern = re.compile(target_regex, re.IGNORECASE)

mylists=['p-1.1', 'P-5']

target_object_is_found = pattern.findall(''.join(mylists))

print "target_object_is_found:", target_object_is_found
```

---

this will give

```
target_object_is_found: ['P-1.1P-5']
```

but from my regex what i need is P-1.1 alone eliminating P-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `join`ed the items in `mylist` and `P-5` is no longer at the start of the string.

You may use

```
import re

target_regex = 'P-[5-8]'
pattern = re.compile(target_regex, re.IGNORECASE)
mylists=['p-1.1', 'P-5']
target_object_is_found = [x for x in mylists if not pattern.match(x)]
print("target_object_is_found: {}".format(target_object_is_found))
# => target_object_is_found: ['p-1.1']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KkLkHv).

Here, the `P-[5-8]` pattern is compiled with `re.IGNORECASE` flag and is used to check each item inside `mylist` (see the `[...]` list comprehension) with the `regex_objext.match` method that looks for a match at the start of string only. The match result is reversed, see `not` after `if`.

So, all items are returned that do not start with `(?i)P-[5-8]` pattern.